Adding a plugin to CKEditor5
I have a react project that I am trying to integrate CKEditor5. I was able to run it with the non-premium plugins from the official editor but i need to add some non official plugins that i found from github. But no matter which one i try, i get this error:
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-size-custom.svg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: unknown file: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
   5 |   ...props
   6 | }, svgRef) {
>  7 |   return <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano" viewBox="0 0 20 20" ref={svgRef} aria-labelledby={titleId} {...props}>{title ? <title id={titleId}>{title}</title> : null}<path d="M.95 1.43a.95.95 0 0 0-.95.95v3.1a.95.95 0 0 0 .95.95h.75v6.3H.95a.95.95 0 0 0-.95.95v3.1a.95.95 0 0 0 .95.95h3.1a.95.95 0 0 0 .95-.95v-.65h1.932l1.539-1.5H5v-.95a.95.95 0 0 0-.95-.95H3.2v-6.3h.85A.95.95 0 0 0 5 5.48v-.55h10v.55a.95.95 0 0 0 .95.95h3.1a.95.95 0 0 0 .95-.95v-3.1a.95.95 0 0 0-.95-.95h-3.1a.95.95 0 0 0-.95.95v1.05H5V2.38a.95.95 0 0 0-.95-.95H.95zm.55 3.5v-2h2v2h-2zm0 9.3v2h2v-2h-2zm15-11.3v2h2v-2h-2z" /><path d="M8.139 20.004v-2.388l7.045-7.048 2.391 2.391-7.046 7.046h-2.39zm11.421-9.101a.64.64 0 0 1-.138.206l-1.165 1.168-2.391-2.391 1.167-1.163a.63.63 0 0 1 .206-.138.635.635 0 0 1 .243-.049.63.63 0 0 1 .449.187l1.491 1.488c.059.059.108.129.138.206s.049.16.049.243a.6.6 0 0 1-.049.243z" /></svg>;
     |                                                  ^^^^^^^
   8 | }
   9 | const ForwardRef = React.forwardRef(SvgObjectSizeCustom);
  10 | export default __webpack_public_path__ + "static/media/object-size-custom.d396432702cfc76e46b9146e22b7a1d7.svg";
    at File.buildCodeFrameError (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:202:12)
    at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js:116:21)
    at PluginPass.JSXNamespacedName (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/create-plugin.js:81:24)
    at newFn (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:160:14)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:46:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:36:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:82:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:61:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:110:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:61:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:110:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:61:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:110:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:89:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:22:17)
    at traverse (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:52:34)
    at transformFile (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:82:31)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/ecems/my-ckeditor-app 3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:24:12)
ERROR
[eslint] 
src/RichTextEditor.js
  Line 35:9:  Duplicate key 'toolbar'  no-dupe-keys

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

I tried to solve it with chatGPT but it is no help.
this is my component that i call in my App.js that has the editor in it:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import CustomEditor from './ckeditor/build/ckeditor'; // Adjust the path if necessary
import translations from 'ckeditor5/translations/tr.js';
import ExportDocument from 'ckeditor5-export-document/src/exportDocument';

const RichTextEditor = () => {
  const [editorData, setEditorData] = useState('');

  const handleEditorChange = (event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    setEditorData(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>CKEditor 5 with React</h2>
      <CKEditor
        editor={CustomEditor}
        data={editorData}
        onChange={handleEditorChange}
        config={{
          plugins:[ExportDocument],
          language: 'tr',
          translations: [translations],
          toolbar: [
            'undo', 'redo', 'bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
            'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'heading', '|',
            'alignment:left', 'alignment:center', 'alignment:right', 'alignment:justify', 'outdent', 'indent' , '|',
            'numberedList', 'bulletedList', '|',
            'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor' , '|', 'pageBreak' , 'specialCharacters' , '|', 
            'imageInsert', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed', 'link', 'horizontalLine', 'code', 'codeBlock',

        ],
        toolbar:{ items:['export-document']},
          fontSize: {
            options: [
              'default',
              9,
              11,
              13,
              15,
              17,
              19,
              21,
          ]
          },
          fontFamily: {
            options: [
              'default',
              'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
              'Courier New, Courier, monospace',
              'Georgia, serif',
              'Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif',
              'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif',
              'Times New Roman, Times, serif',
              'Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif',
              'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'
            ]
          },
          fontColor: {
            colors: [
              {
                color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)',
                label: 'Black'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(0, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Red'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(30, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Orange'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(60, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Yellow'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(90, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Light Green'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(120, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Green'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(150, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Aquamarine'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(180, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Turquoise'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(210, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Light Blue'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(240, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Blue'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(270, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Purple'
              }
            ],
            columns: 5,
            documentColors: 10,
            defaultColor: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)' // Set default font color to black
          },
          fontBackgroundColor: {
            colors: [
              {
                color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)',
                label: 'White'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)',
                label: 'Black'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(0, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Red'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(30, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Orange'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(60, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Yellow'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(90, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Light Green'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(120, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Green'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(150, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Aquamarine'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(180, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Turquoise'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(210, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Light Blue'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(240, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Blue'
              },
              {
                color: 'hsl(270, 75%, 60%)',
                label: 'Purple'
              }
            ]
          }
        }}
      />
      <h3>Content:</h3>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: editorData }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RichTextEditor;

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how i can fix it?
I have tried to implement any solutions from chatgpt. Like this one:
To fix the issue caused by the namespace tag in the SVG file, you can remove the xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano" attribute from the SVG tag. Here’s how you can do it:

    1.  Open the object-size-custom.svg file and locate the xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano" attribute.
    2.  Remove the namespace attribute 


Could you share some of these nonofficial custom plugins that you found from github? Also, the problem seems most likely related to the configurations of the react bundler. What is your react bundler (webpack, vite etc.)?

To list some of them:
https://github.com/antoniolucasnobar/ckeditor5-export-document/tree/master
https://github.com/phudak3/ckeditor5-emoji
I am using create-react-app. I think it uses webpack?

I reproduced the error. However, even after fixing the problem temprorarily by manually replacing  xlmns:v with xlmnsV, then another error is being raised from ckeditor-emoji package. Unfortunately, the versions of the packages are incompatible and no new build is published for more than 2 years. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@phudak/ckeditor5-emoji
